# Scraping dos opciones a find_element_by_class_name

Tags: python, selenium, scraping

Estoy aprendiendo a usar python con selenium, y no logro resolver al hacer scraping en una web que tiene quizas en algunos productos ubicaciones clases distintas para mostrar el precio (por ejemplo si esta de oferta)
Es esto posible? porque me da como resultado 0 y no deberia.
Gracias!!

````
   def get_product_price(self, url):
     self.driver.get(url)
     time.sleep(4)
     precioBuscar = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('offer-price')               
    
     if precioBuscar: 
         print ("primera opcion")
         precio=precioBuscar.text
     else:
         precioBuscar2 = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('pro-price')    
         if precioBuscar2:
             print ("segunda opcion")
             precio=precioBuscar2.text
         else:
             precio=0
     

     return precio ```
````

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un extracto del código de la página web que estás explotando, o la URL?

Comment: Hola!! Gracias por responder. Mi duda principal, es como lograr con el codigo tener un IF como se logra en otros lenguajes. en este ejemplo, el producto de la pagina A tiene clase "offer-price" y en la pagina B tiene clase "pro-price", dependiendo si esta en oferta o no. Tampoco puedo aplicar xpath porque lo cambia de ubicacion respecto al html y cambia el id.